# Integrating $\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{x^2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Fourier transforming the function:
$$f(t) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1;  & \mbox{ } |t| \leq 1 \\
  0; & \mbox{otherwise} 
 \end{array}
\right.$$
We get:
$$F(y)=2 \frac{\sin y}{y}$$
And now applying Parseval's identity for the Fourier transform,

$$\int_{- \infty}^\infty {4 \frac{\sin ^2 y}{y^2}dy}=\int_{-1}^1 {f(t)^2}dt=2$$
By linearity of the integral we get the result $\frac{1}{2}$, however the result is $\pi$. Where did I go wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What is equal to $1/2$?

Comment: The integral of $\sin^2 (x) / x^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your result for the Fourier transform of $f$ indicates that you use the definition

$$\mathcal{F}[f](y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-ity}\,dt$$

of the Fourier transform (or maybe even with $e^{ity}$ instead of $e^{-ity}$).

With that definition, the Fourier transform is not an isometry of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and Plancherel's theorem becomes

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert \mathcal{F}[f](y)\rvert^2\,dy = 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert f(t)\rvert^2\,dt.$$

Then the result you get is indeed $\pi$.